# History.pushState: Going back in history after loading the actual pushed state url

Tags: javascript, browser-history, html5-history

I have a website with an overlay. Here is my problem:

1. I am on page 1 and click on a text that opens an overlay using JS and also uses `history.pushState()` to change the url accordingly:

`history.pushState(null, "Page 2", "/page/2")`

2. Then I reload the page using the browser reload button, which forces my application to go to the actual url (page 2) that I previously pushed using `history.pushState()`
3. Now when I click the browser back button, I expect to go back to page 1, but instead nothing happens apart from the browser changing the url and title to the ones of page 1 - the site itself does not reload.

I don't know why this happens. I have a simple hack that works, but it feels super dirty:

```
window.addEventListener("popstate", function(e) {
            let title = document.title
            setTimeout(() => {
                if (document.title === title) {
                    location.reload()
                }
            }, 100)
        })
```

This hack works, because although the browser changes the title in the browser when going back, the title of the document remains the same, because the website does not refresh. So then I force the refresh.

Answer (score 0):

history.pushState changes the URL but doesn't reload the page, have you tried with location.href?

P.D. I'm assuming you're not in a single page application. If you are, don't do location.href or you will force an unnecessary refresh.

Comment: I don't want to reload the page, I just want the overlay to show the content. You can think of it like on the Instagram page, clicking on a picture will open an overlay and not reload the website.